# why the UpdateAPIView view throwing error while updating?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have written a very simple UpdateAPIView. Below is the code.

views.py

```
class IndividualUserUpdate(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = NewEmployeeProfile.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'first_name'
```

urls.py

```
path('updat/<str:first_name>/update/', IndividualUserUpdate.as_view(), name='updat'),
```

when I try to update any field in my postman, I am getting below errors in my CMD prompt:

```
Not Found: /apii/updat/ami/update/
```

from postman

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/apii/updat/ami/update/
```

Any suggestions, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```py
path('updat/<str:first_name>/update/', IndividualUserUpdate.as_view(), name='updat'),
```

```
/apii/updat/ami/update/
```

Is your URL included somewhere? The initial `/apii` isn't covered through your defined path.

Comment: yes, the APP url is included in project level URL. Therefore, its as per the rule. Thanks

Comment: can you try: `reverse('app:updat', {'first_name': 'fName'})` from your shell and see, if the namespace is registered inside URLConf.

Comment: Ok, will check and let you know, thanx